# How to fix GPU Driver Issue error when running the Android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

My android emulator was working perfectly a few weeks ago but has now given me an error. When I run the code, a GPU Driver Issue error dialogue pops up along with the emulator. When I click "OK", the android emulator does not run the app as expected.

The error is as follows:

`Your GPU driver information:`


`...`


`Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available.`

Here's a screenshot of the error, followed by a screenshot of the results of clicking "OK":

[image: GPU driver issue error when running the Android emulator]

[image: GPU driver issue error stopping Android app in emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this issue recently. I solved it by updating my emulator and related files in Android Studio. I believe you can do this by clicking "Help" -> "Check for updates" in Android Studio and then letting it install all updates.

You may need to check for updates from the "Beta channel" (it is usually "Stable channel" by default). You can do this by clicking File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates and making sure to check the "Automatically check for updates" box, as well as "Beta channel" in the drop-down list.

[Android Studio updates settings to fix GPU driver issue with emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yQ4V.png)

After this is all completed, try restarting Android Studio and then do a fresh clean/rebuild of the project.

More in-depth info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I checked for all updates, and after I ran the program, all the features of the app (button, plain text, etc) were all jammed up at the top. Then I exited it, ran it again, and then the issue pops up again. What do I do now, since I've updated it?

Comment: Did you make sure to check for updates from "Beta channel" and not "Stable channel" in the Updates menu? If you did that, accepted/downloaded all updates, and then did a fresh clean/rebuild of the project, my next suggestion would be to make sure that your Intel GPU driver really is up to date as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the issues started after updating to latest versions. Android Studio 2.3.3, SDK tools 26.0.2, SDK platform tools 26.0.0, emulator 26.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 on stable channel. Am a bit hesitant to try beta channel.

Comment: Don't do this. It installed Android Studio 3.0.0-b2 and upgraded a bunch of other dependencies. Now both old and new Android Studio do not get correct versions and cannot build the project. Need to totally clean and reinstall everything!

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver I have had no such issue and upgrading to current software versions for Android Studio, the SDK, etc is highly recommended. It sounds like you have a personal build problem, not a global update issue. Checking for updates on the beta channel has solved the issue for at least 2 people now.

Answer (score 2):

These steps made the emulator fast for me in my Dell latitude e7440
    In the AVD manager, edit your emulator.
   Emulated performance- Graphics set to Software- 
   GLES2.0
When your emulator starts, on the right side panel click on the three dots(extended controls) 
    Go to settings tab- advanced.
    Select OpenGL ES renderer - ANGLE(D3D11)
    OpenGL ES API level - Renderer maximum

Restart your emulator.

Got the idea from here 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration

angle_indirect: (Windows only) Use a Quick Boot-compatible variant of ANGLE Direct3D to render graphics using software acceleration. This option is a good alternative to host mode if your computer can't use hardware acceleration. In most cases, ANGLE performance should be similar to using host mode because ANGLE uses Microsoft DirectX instead of OpenGL. On Windows, Microsoft DirectX drivers typically have fewer issues than OpenGL drivers. This option uses Direct3D 11 and requires Windows 10, Windows 8.1, or Windows 7 SP1 with the Windows 7 Platform Update.

Comment: `emulated performance` option is disabled for me. How to enable it?