# GPU Driver Issue - installing xamarin studio on vs 2019, inside VM from windows 10 dev environment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, hyper-v, android-sdk-manager

Using a laptop with Windows 10 Pro 64 bit as a host, I've used the powershell command from inside the host
`Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true` to turn on Hyper-V inside the VM.

Inside the VM iv selected the windows features 'Hyper-V' and 'Windows Hypervisor Platform',

Using VS 2019, version 16.9.4. Iv added the Nuget packges - 'Xamarin.Essentials v1.6.1' and 'Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2012'

From Android SDK Manager I have the following selected in Platforms and Tools:

[image]

From the Android Manager if I try to start the emulator I get the error message:
**GPU Drive Issue**

[image]Iv been doing alot of research and reading over similar Q's. Is this error caused because the model is using the **Microsoft Basic Render Driver** and is the solution to this to use the graphics card from the host? Would this solve the issue or am I going down the wrong path.

I have tried this by following the guidelines in

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows
```

to check if my laptop can use HAMX, which it can. So Ive downloaded the file from
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases

but when I run the installer it I get the error 'The system requirements are not satisifed'
(just to be clear resolving this issue with HAMX is not my Q, this is just my process of trouble shooting to try and resolve my original question of GPU Driver Issue.

Then I found another post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578220/how-to-fix-gpu-driver-issue-error-when-running-the-android-emulator` with a similar Q....I have tried a comment on here to change the settings -> Advanced -> of 'OpenGL Es renderer(requires restart) -> I have tried SwiftShader and Desktop native OpenGL but to no avail

Next....From `https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html`

I have got the idea to create a new device setting the hw.gpu.mode to host (in the Android device manager), but this is still showing the  GPU Driver error popUp.

Does anyone know what else I can do or help me in anyway please?
Thanks

Comment: From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows), you can't run a VM-accelerated emulator inside another VM, such as a VM hosted by VirtualBox, VMware, or Docker (unless using WSL2). You must run the Android emulator directly on your system hardware.

Comment: ok thanks the reply Cherry